# How to check if locationManager has updated current location?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to show user's current location on startup, and then keep tracking their location but stop centring on the current location. My idea is to centre on the current location in viewDidLoad(), but I don't know how to wait for locationManager to update the current location before centring. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
var currentLocation : CLLocation?
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        // wait for currentLocation to be updated
        animateMap(currentLocation!)

    }

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    currentLocation = locations.last!
}

func animateMap(_ location: CLLocation) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 1000, 1000)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply call that `animateMap(currentLocation!)` function in delegate method `didUpdateLocations` where you are initializing the `currentLocation`.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    currentLocation = locations.last!
    animateMap(currentLocation!)
    //Either Call `stop​Updating​Location()`
    locationManager.stop​Updating​Location()
    //Or you can create one boolean property with default value false and compare it inside this method
    if !animatedFlag {
        animateMap(currentLocation!)
        animatedFlag = true
    }
}

var animatedFlag = false
```

Comment: But this will also call animateMap, which centres on the current location, everytime a location update occurs, right? I don't want this to happen. I only want to centre onto current location on startup.

Comment: @Asteria Then you can stop the location manger to update it or you can use can create one boolean instance property for that either of which suits you.

Comment: This did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

// MARK:- Location lattitude longtitude method Delegate Methods

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    if locationManager.location != nil
    {
        let locValue = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
        lat = locValue.latitude
        long = locValue.longitude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the animateMap function in didUpdateLocations delegate method, instead of in viewDidLoad. And, allow the map to center only the first time. You can you some bool variable for that.

```
var isLocationUpdated = false 

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    currentLocation = locations.last!
    if (!isLocationUpdated)
     {
        animateMap(currentLocation!)
        isLocationUpdated = true
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You have done the same thing. I saw your answer only after i posted mine.